# unable to install composer for Magento 2.4.6 setup throws socket error in windows

Tags: composer, magento2.4.6, windows10, php8.2

While Installing the composer throws the following error

**The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini**

> A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the
> 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or a dll does not exist.
>
> Program Output: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
> library 'php_Sockets.d11' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_Sockets.d11
> (The specified module could not be found),
> C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_Sockets.d11.dll (The specified module could
> not be found))

I have tried following

The path for extensions in php.ini has been changed to Absolute path
Cross verified whether the extension present in the specified path

But still facing the same issue, do anyone have any idea about it?

Am using xampp server & Windows OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go into your **xampp** and open **Apache -> Config** then click on **php.ini** file.
Once file is open then search for **socket** extension, if you find that extension then **remove the semicolon(;)** from it.

If this is not available in your **xampp's php.ini** then directly add `extension=sockets`
in **php.ini** where other extensions were added.

After saving the file **Restart** your Apache and Check issue is resolved or not.